# Git pull with access-token , fails with other user

Tags: windows, gitlab, access-token

I have cloned git repo with access token

git clone http://oauth2:@myrepo.git  from user A on windows

and when I switch to user B and try to git pull on same repo

gives -

error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD:

---

All I want to achieve is

user A and B should be able to pull code from myrepo.git when cloned with access-token

Comment: with access token you mean SSH keys right?

Comment: gitlab access tokens

Comment: What kind of access token did you create?

Comment: access token with all read access , role is set to developer